# Trying to walk the tree to a RelativeLayout in a ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am trying to get a handle on the `RelativeLayout` that defines how a row in a `ListView` should be laid out. I am getting null and I believe it is because one of two things.

Possibility one is that it is not inflated yet so it returns null....While I've read about this one I am very shaky on the inflation concept. I have been programming in Java for 3 weeks now (from C#).
So I'm not sure how to test, much less handle. For example all I do is set the adapter to the list view....not sure what event or when exactly the inflation happens under the covers.

Possibility two is that I'm not walking the tree properly.

My Parent:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:minHeight="320dp" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/rlay_LftDataParent" 
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/lstvw_LiftData" />
```

The row definition (the layout I am trying to set the min height for)

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:id="@+id/rlay_LftDataRw" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/background">
...
</RelativeLayout>
```

In the Activity I've tried: (lstvw_LiftData is my ListView object)

```
RelativeLayout RowLayout = (RelativeLayout)lstvw_LiftData.findViewById(R.id.rlay_LftDataRw);
```

and

```
RelativeLayout RowLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rlay_LftDataRw);
```

If you are curious to know the bigger picture this is a follow on question from this post [Using RelativeLayout to control a ListView row height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10635618/using-relativelayout-to-control-a-listview-row-height) where I'm trying to get the row layout to fill the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't access a `View` from the `ListView` row with `findViewById`. Instead use the adapter to get a reference of your `RelativeLayout` in the `getView` method and there set the width and height. You didn't say what adapter do you use so here is a simple example for the basic `ArrayAdapter`:

**Edit:**
You don't call the `getView()` method yourself, the adapter will call the `getView` method automatically when it's time to show a new row. Regarding the question from your last comment, if the custom `Adapter` class is a inner class in the `Activity` where you'll use it:

```
public class SomeActivity extends ListActivity {

     private int mHeight, mWidth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // ...do what ever stuff you need in this activity
       // find out the height/width values:
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        mHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
        mWidth = metrics.widthPixels;   
        // set the adapter
        setListAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this,
                R.layout.adapters_listview_rowheight, R.id.textView1, items));
    }

    //you use your own adapter class
    private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                int textViewResourceId, String[] objects) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    //do whatever logic you need here
                    // finally you end up with the RelativeLayout you'll return as the view for the row
                    // before you return set the desired values for its width and height
            rl.getLayoutParams().height = mHeight;
            rl.getLayoutParams().width = mWidth;
            return rl;
        }


    }

}
```

If you `Adapter` class is in another file then make the constructor of that adapter to take two `int` values representing the width and height:

```
//the constructor
public CustomAdapter(/*whatever parameters you already have*/, int height, int width) {
    //do stuff
    //now you also have a reference for the width and height that you can use in the getView method.
}
```

and in your `Activity`(with the same code for the onCreate method):

```
setListAdapter(new CustomAdapter(/*whatever parameters you already have*/, mHeight, mWidth));
```

I don't know if this is what you want.

Comment: I'm following everything except the params to pass. I am using a custom adapter so your example works well I just don't know what to pass to getView override. In my activity I am calling RelativeLayout X = (RelativeLayout)LiftDataAdapter.getView(position, convertView, parent); which will hit my override I just don't know the params?  On a seperate not you state to use mHeight which is fine except I don't know how to get that param from the activity scope to the custom adapter scope. Do I create a method to pass it before calling getView?

Comment: OK I get it now. getView is called for my by the system as it populates so my question remains on how to get the values from the activity scope to the adapter scope.

Comment: Yes indeed that answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

You access your rows via the `Adapter`.  In something like `getView`, but depending on the `Adapter` you are using, it may be different.